# Data Validation not filling when adding row to table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table I'm using to track issues.  Two of the columns have data validation based on lists and there is conditional formatting set up on a few of the columns as well.  When I add a new row to the table by typing something in the next row after the table ends, one of the data validations doesn't get added to the new row.  The other data validation does get filled down and the conditional formatting all does as well.  I can't figure out what's different about that column that is preventing it from automatically filling.

If I right click in a cell in the last row and select Insert Table Row Below, it does fill the validation, which is a decent workaround but since I'm used to just typing in the cell below to add rows to the table, it would be nice to have that work.

I can add screenshots if someone thinks it would help answer this but I'm hoping there's just some setting I'm not finding that is meant to cause this behavior.

Comment: The different is not between the columns, but the fact, that when you start typing in the first column, that row is not yet part of the table, so data validation isn't applied there. When you've entered the data into that cell, the table auto-expands, so both conditional formatting and data validation are applied. The only solution I can think of is to write a macro which always expands the table to the first empty row.

Comment: The column I typically type in is not one of the ones with Data Validation.  They are both a few columns to the right.  After I type in the name of the client in the first column, the table automatically expands to include the new row.  One of the columns with Data Validation has that validation copied down to the new row in the table and the other one doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried re-creating that data valuation? Can you share an example?

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this problem as well and the solutions previously supplied did not work because I had several rows above my table (i.e. the table started in row 7). Here is what worked for me.

- Hover your mouse over the header of the column in question and you'll
  see a downward arrow.
- Click once to select the column and you'll see that the data rows are
  highlighted.
- Click a second time and you'll see that the column header is now also
  selected along with the data.
- At this point you can apply your data validation rule and it should
  apply to any new rows subsequently added.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Selecting the table's column instead of the sheet's entire column is the key. I had to skip the third step above, though, as clicking a second time disables the "Data validation" button...

Comment: This worked for me as long as I had more than one data row and I clicked the column header arrow as many times as it took to select the column data but not the column header. Then I had to enter the validation rules from scratch. Once entered, I could delete any unnecessary data rows to return to an empty table.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with data validation not being copied in new rows and the following worked for me:

select the whole column, including the header and apply the data validation rule. As the column header will have the validation too, go back and clear it (set it to any value). After this, new rows will have the data validation automatically set

regards,

Answer (score 0):

Select the column that you're applying the data validation to.  Make sure to select the entire column by clicking on the *letter* of the column, not by selecting a cell range.

Typically, in a table, when you first select the column, it highlights only the *data* section of the table.  (For example, if you're selecting column C of a 12-row table with headers, when you click on column C itself, a black box is drawn around C2-C12, because Excel knows C1 is a header and that you don't actually need C13+ for your table.  It thinks it's helping by only selecting this "meat" of your table.) If you apply data validation at this point, then add a row of data to your table in C13, you won't have your data validation auto-populate because you've (unknowingly) only selected C2-C12.

Instead, click on column C *again*.  Now your selection black box includes C1 and continues indefinitely down the page. Now apply data validation.  When you enter data in row C13 (or C14, or C15, etc.), you will always have your data validation auto-populate into the table. I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

I looked for different options, and for those who would like to "keep it clean" wouldn't like to select the complete Column letter, because else the first Row (header row) will show as if it is not meeting the right criteria.

So what I did was:

1. Select the complete column letter, then "Data Validation" and select "Any Value"
2. Select your column data (selecting the column close to the header row), this will only select your table's column, then "Data Validation" and select your validations as desired
3. Add a new row by typing below the last available row of the table and the validation will now be inherited :)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same problem, and Google led me here (among many other places too....).

Precisely ZERO of the solutions here and elsewhere worked in my case.  Do not know why....

My issue: a table in which some (not all) of the columns had Validation applied.  For one and only one of the columns, any method which adds rows, whether manual or via VBA code, produced the same result... that particular column did not get the Validation copied to the new rows.  All other columns were AOK.  It did not matter where that column was; as long as it existed at all, the same problem.  Even deleting it and restoring manually didnt work.

I ended up re-creating the entire table manually, "pasting" the data from the old table to the new one, then replacing the old table with the new one.  This involved a fair amount of trial and error. The important point was to RE-NAME the original table first so that references to it (formulas and pivot tables elsewhere in the workbook) were updated.
After killing the old table (by converting to range and deleting everything), I replaced it with the new one.  Then I renamed it back to the original name; this was in order to preserve references to it in the VBA code, which do not get updated when you change names!

In the end, I now had a rebuilt table and everything works, including the Validation being properly copied to new rows.

I still have no idea how the problem occurred, nor why all the other suggestions found here and elsewhere did not work for my case.  Somehow, it was just "corrupted" and rebuilding it fixed it.

Best of luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to this issue and I came up with this:

```
Function addSimulation()
    ' adds new row of simulation data        

    On Error GoTo ERROR   

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TabelleSimulation")

    Dim newrow As ListRow

    ' add row on **SECOND** place - only to make sure data validation fields are copied as well
    Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add(2) 
    With newrow
        .Range(1) = "some data"
        .Range(2) = Date
        .Range(3) = "more data"
        .Range(1).Select ' select a cell, so this row can be moved
    End With

    ' move row one up
    Selection.EntireRow.Cut
    Selection.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
    GoTo Ende

ERROR:
'Bei Error:

GoTo Ende

Ende:
' ENDE!

End Function
```

Just add your new row at the **second** place and then move it up. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a new row to the table by typing something in the next row after the table ends, go to the last cell in your table and add a new row by pressing TAB. All data validation will be entered correctly. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the error tends to occur when you move the position of the column with the list data validation applied. I have a table with multiple data validation lists and when I move one of those columns the validation doesn't expand on to new rows but the validation for other columns does.

The only way to get the validation to work again was to delete and recreate the column in the desired position.